# Proof that $\mathbb{R}$ is connected

Tags: general-topology

If i suppose that $\mathbb{R}$ is not connected, then there exists $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ is closed and open , where $\emptyset\neq A\neq \mathbb{R}$

How to continue with this methode ?

Edit: Let $x\notin A$ we suppose that $A\cap ]-\infty,x]\neq \emptyset$ (or we work with that set $A\cap [x,+\infty[$ )

this set is closed and open sice $x\notin A$ and it is bounded from upper by $x$

so there exists $y=\sup (A\cap ]-\infty,x])$, As $A\cap ]-\infty,x]$ is open; $\exists \varepsilon>0, ]y-\varepsilon, y+\varepsilon[\subset (A\cap ]-\infty, x])$

Where is the contradiction please

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $x\notin A$, then $A\cap(-\infty,x]$ is closed and $A\cap(-\infty,x)$ is open. But since $x\notin A$, this is the same set.

So we can assume that $x=\sup A$. Now derive a contradiction, since $\sup A\in A$ for all closed $A$.

Comment: what you mean by :"since $x\notin A$ this is the same set ?

Comment: $A\cap(-\infty,x)=A\cap(-\infty,x]$.

Comment: ok,  but i don't understand the idea we must find contradiction with what ? and what we do with the fact that $A\cap (-\infty,x]$ is closed ?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Pick some $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus A$ and $y\in A$. Suppose WLOG that $x<y$; think about the interval $(x, y)$. You want to find some point where, going from $x$ to $y$, we "switch" from $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$ to $A$ *(could such a point be in either $A$ or $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$? use the fact that they're both open . . .)*; so, do you see a way to apply the least upper bound property here?

Comment: i don't see , i don't understand

Comment: @Vrouvrou What part don't you understand?

Comment: You want to find some point where, going from x to y, we "switch" from R∖A to A (could such a point be in either A or R∖A? use the fact that they're both open . . .); so, do you see a way to apply the least upper bound property here?

Comment: Please what is the contradiction here ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou It's the part in the parentheses. If there were such a point, it would have to be in either $A$ or $A$'s complement; but each of these sets is open, so some *neighborhood* around this point would be entirely in one set or entirely in the other. But that means it's not a "switching point". Of course that's informal, but it hopefully gives you enough intuition to start in the right direction . . .

Comment: If you see the answer of  Asaf Karagila, he suppose that $x\notin A$ then $A\cap ]-\infty, x]$ is closed, how to continue after that ?

Comment: HINT: If $A\cap ]-\infty, x]$ is closed, then can you show $x$ must be in $A\cap ]-\infty, x]$? Think about what $x$ is . . .

Comment: no $x\notin A$ so $x$ c'an't be in $A\cap]-\infty,x]$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53571/discussion-between-vrouvrou-and-noah-schweber).

Comment: @Vrouvrou I know - **that's the contradiction**.

Comment: but why $A\cap ]-\infty,x]\neq \emptyset$ ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical result, and you will find many treatments of it in the literature. A hint is that the crucial difference between the reals and the rationals is that the satisfy the upper bound property. So it is natural to consider the supremum/infimum of the sets forming the disconnection. It is technically a bit simpler to show that a segment is connected.

There are alternatives to the classical arguments, explored in [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268747898_Metric_characterization_of_connectedness_for_topological_spaces) paper. Briefly, connectedness can be phrased in terms of connecting walks, very similarly to how path connectedness is phrased. With one only needs to show that given ant two points in $\mathbb R$ and any scale, a connecting walk exists, which is not hard to do. If resorting to the compactness of a closed segment is allowed, then that part becomes trivial, since the scale may be assumed to be uniform.

Answer (score 0):

Let  $A$ be open and closed with $x\in A$ .

(i). Let $S^+=\{y: y>x\land [x,y)\subset A\}.$ Then $S^+$ is not empty (because $A$ is open, so $A\supset (-r+x,r+x)$ for some $r>0,$ so $r+x\in S^+$).

Suppose $y_+=\sup S^+$ exists in $\mathbb R.$ Then $y_+\in A$

This is because,  for any $z\in (x,y_+)$ there is some $y\in (z,s_+]\cap S,$ so $z\in (x,y)\subset A.$.. So $(x,y_+)\subset A,$ and $A$ is closed, so $y_+\in A.$

But now we have  a contradiction because $(-r+y_+,r+y_+)\subset A$ for some $r>0,$ so  $A\supset [x,y_+]\cup (y_+, r+y_+)=[x,r+y_+),$ implying $\sup S^+\geq r+y_+>y_+=\sup S^+.$

We conclude that $\sup S^+$ does not exist, so $A\supset [x,\infty).$

(ii). Let $(-A)=\{-z: z\in A\}.$ Then $(-A)$ is open and closed. Applying the above argument to $(-A)$ we have $(-A)\supset [-x,\infty)$. Therefore $A\supset (-\infty, x].$

(iii). From  (i) and (ii) we have $A=\mathbb R.$

Comment: why $r+y_+\leq sup S^+ $ ?

Comment: Because $r+y_+>x$ and $A\supset [x, r+y_+)$ .So by the def'n of $S^+$ we have $ r+y_+\in S^+$, which implies $\sup S^+\geq r+y_+.$